# Using command prompt to execute .java

Tags: java, eclipse, command-line

I am trying to use the command line to execute a java class but I am receiving the below error

"error could not find or load main class
caused by java.lang.noclassdeffounderror"

I could used the "javac" to create my java class but then I ma getting this error.

Thank you for any help,

Regards

```
package start;

public class sdz1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World !");

    }

}
```

---

I just found that is not working when I am in the src folder created by eclipse where my ".java" is located.
Anyone has a explanation why is not working in this case ?

Comment: https://beginnersbook.com/2013/05/first-java-program/

Comment: You should add an example of what your code looks like because we cant solve an error we cant see.

Comment: It is basically a "Hello World"

Comment: package start;

public class sdz1 {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  System.out.println("Hello World !");

 }

}

Comment: did you get it to work?

Answer (score 0):

Check you've all required classes present at runtime as those were available at compile time

```
NoClassDefFoundError :- comes when Java Virtual Machine is not able to find a particular class at runtime which was available at compile time
```

Read more: https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/06/noclassdeffounderror-exception-in.html#ixzz6VZaZBT8y

Answer (score 0):

Check that you have written all the "public class..." and the main method. If you then compile it, it shouldn't give you errors.

Comment: the class is "public"

Answer (score 0):

If your program is in directory *start*, execute this from the directory just above that to compile:

```
javac start/*.java
```

and then execute this to run:

```
java start/sdz1
```